# Checkbox always return true value irrespective of status of checkbox

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am using a checkbox inside a  of meteor framework. Whether I checked it or unchecked it, it always returns true value. I have already tried many options available on net.

The code is as below:-

Below is the code of the form:-

```
<template name="subscribedKeyword"> 
    <div class="issue" > 
        <div class="issue-content">
            <h3>
                {{category}} 
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

                <input id='pp' class="checktype" name="mark" type="checkbox"  value="1" {{{done}}} />Get Notifications
                <input type="hidden" name="mark" value="0" />
            </h3>
    </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Below is the code of .js file

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function(e){
    if($(this).prop('checked'))
    {
        $(this).next().val(1);
        alert('$(this).next().val(1); '+$(this).next().val(1));

        // Adding the loggedin user to the collection on checking the checkbox
        Subscribed.update(id, {$addToSet: {categorySubscribedUsers : Meteor.user()}});
        alert('value added to the subscribed collection');
        var msg = "Hello "+ managerName +",\n\n"+ userName";

        var subOfSubscribedDomain = 'Notification of Subscribed Domain';

        //Send mail to Manager
        alert('mail to mgr regarding subscription by user of domain');
    Meteor.call('sendEmail',
                  managerEmailId,
                  senderEmail,
                  msg,
                      id,
                  subOfSubscribedDomain); 

    } 
    else
    {
        $(this).next().val(0);
        alert('pulling of data from subscribed collection');
        var subscribedPersons = Subscribed.findOne({category:       issueManagerCategory}).categorySubscribedUsers;

    if(subscribedPersons && subscribedPersons.length)
    {
            var j;
            for(j= 0;j< subscribedPersons.length;j++)
            {
        if(subscribedPersons[j].username === Meteor.user().username)
        {   
            var personId=subscribedPersons[j]._id;

                    Subscribed.update(id,{$pull:{categorySubscribedUsers:{_id:personId}}});

                var msg = "Hello "+ managerName 
            var subOfUnSubscribedDomain = 'Notification of UnSubscribed Domain';
                    // Send mail to manager
            Meteor.call('sendEmail',
                         managerEmailId,
                     senderEmail,
                     msg,
                 id,
                     subOfUnSubscribedDomain); 
                             break; 
            }
            }

         }
      }
});
```

I have tried:-

- document.getElementById()
- $('').is(':checked')

Everything that could be possible. But still clueless, any pointer what to do ??``

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
if(document.getElementById('checkbox1').checked==true)
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you have this opening quotation mark:

```
var msg = "Hello "+ managerName +",\n\n"+ userName";
                                                  ^
```

Everything from that `"` right up until the `});` at the end is being treated as a string, and your JavaScript is throwing:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
```